# admob doesn't send my money to my bank account with ach wire

Tags: android, admob, currency

In transfers I can see that there is invoice with some Id and date when the transfer of the money have happen. But when I went to the bank they told me that I do not have any money.

I am 100% sure that my IBAN code my SWIFT code and so on are correctly written . . .

Does anybody have suggestions what the problem might be ?

Is there some delay after the invoice is written on the admob account and the actual payment to the bank ?

is there some place where I can get informed about this things ?

thanks

if this is not the place to ask this please tall me where to ask

Comment: This is not a place to ask about this. For issues like this, I would try to reach the official admob support channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my local bank account

Comment: how did you resolved that ? I see a complete transaction summary in admob new account payment page but never got the money in my bank